# division by 0 error when passing my ppmi matrix to LsiModels

Tags: python, gensim, svd

I constructed a ppmi matrix using the pmi_scorer from gensim and a single huge corpus. Each line is read into and processed as a single document. To avoid memory overload I create all matrices with dtype=int16.

I feed my ppmi matrix into LsiModels using sparse2corpus. When I run svd using LsiModels I get the following error.

> lsimodel.py:102: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
> rel_spectrum = np.abs(1.0 - np.cumsum(s / np.sum(s)))

The error message appears for the larger models but not for the (factor 1000) smaller ones, so I don't think it has to do with corpus size.

My code is a s follows. First I create a co-occurence matrix by counting the co-occurrences and then transform this into a sparse matrix.
I then calculate PPMI scores for the sparse co-occurrence matrix using gensim (p)pmi scorer:

```
    ppmi_matrix = sp.lil_matrix(cooc_matrix.shape, dtype=np.int16)
    for i, j, v in zip(cooc_matrix.row, cooc_matrix.col, cooc_matrix.data):
        worda_count = vocab_df.iloc[i, 0]
        wordb_count = vocab_df.iloc[j, 0]
        ppmi_score = ppmi_scorer(worda_count, wordb_count, v, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count)
        ppmi_matrix[i, j] = ppmi_score
        ppmi_matrix[j, i] = ppmi_score

    del cooc_matrix
    # Convert the sparse matrix to a Gensim-compatible corpus
    corpus_sparse = Sparse2Corpus(ppmi_matrix)
    
    del ppmi_matrix

    # FINAL STEP: SVD
    id2word = dict(enumerate(vocab_df.index.tolist()))
    model = LsiModel(corpus_sparse, id2word=id2word, num_topics=vector_size)
    
    del corpus_sparse
```

Would it make sense to try and perform svd using another package/approach?
It seems that LsiModel raises this error sometimes if the dataset is too small (but I get the error for the larger corpora instead of the smaller ones). Perhaps anyone has encountered similar problems and found a way how to deal with this?